# Сортировка слиянием (абстрактное обменное)

Tags: c++, c

Имеется программа, осуществляющая сортировку массива методом нисходящего слияния (слияние абстрактное обменное), но работает она на массивах максимум до 20 элементов
Подскажите пожалуйста, что сделать, чтобы программа позволяла обрабатывать массивы объемом до 10000 элементов?

```
void merge(int a[], int l, int m, int r)
    { int i, j, n;
    int *aux;
      aux = new int;  
        for (i = m+1; i > l; i--) {aux[i-1] = a[i-1];}
        for (j = m; j < r; j++) {aux[r+m-j] = a[j + 1];}
        for (int k = l; k <= r; k++) {
            if (aux[j] < aux[i]) {
                a[k] = aux[j--];}
            else {
                a[k] = aux[i++];}
        }
        delete [] aux;
    }

void sort(int a[], int l, int r)
    { if (r <= l) return;
        int m = (r+l)/2;
        sort(a, l, m);
        sort(a, m+1, r);
        merge(a, l, m, r);
    }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int m, n, i, j;
    int l = n-1;


    printf("Vvedite razmernost massiva: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int a[n];
    printf("Massiv do sortirovki: ");
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++) a[i] = rand()%200/(rand()%100)-rand()%70;
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");


    sort(a, 0, n-1);


    printf("Massiv posle sortirovki: ");
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Что сделать"? Исправить ошибки в программе. Алгоритм сортировки слиянием не имеет ограничения на число элементов.

Comment: В таком случае укажите пожалуйста на ошибки

Answer (score 2):

В коде много бессмыслицы

- ```
  int *aux;
  aux = new int;  
  // Выделяется единственный `int`

  // Далее `aux` используется как массив размера более 1 (!!!)

  delete [] aux; 
  // Почему после `new` вдруг делается `delete []`?
  ```
- ```
  for(i = 0; i<n; i++) a[i] = rand()%200/(rand()%100)-rand()%70;
  ```

  Деление на `rand()%100` - потенциальное деление на `0`
- Использование `new` говорит о том, что вы хотите использовать С++. Но вот такой код

  ```
  int m, n, i, j;

  int a[n]; // <- Не допускается в С++
  ```

  приемлем только в C. Размеры массивов в С++ должны быть константами времени компиляции.

Comment: Я новичок и плохо разбираюсь в с++. Если вас не затруднит, не могли бы вы помочь с правильной инициализацией массивов и исправлением моих ошибок? Желательно с пояснением